# Rails: polymorphic model or different models for different sizes of images?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, oop, amazon-s3

I got a RoR application and have a **Photo** model that belongs to a **Car**.

**Photo** stores an image that is resized by 200x200>.

Now I have to add another entity with some other type of images into my app (**CarModel** class and its photos).

It would be nice if I could use Photo via polymorphic associations with other models. BUT: it seems that I will have to use another type of thumbnails for this class (not 200x200>).

**What should I do?**

1. Create CarModelPhoto class and use it with Car model?
2. Add polymorphc associations so that Photo could belong to other classes that Car.
3. Use tools (like Blitline or Cloudinary) that resize images on the fly so that Photo's image stops being limited to 200x200px. - But I store images on S3 - it seems like it would be bad for performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you need to implement your 2 image models, you basically have 2 approachs

DRY: if you plan to implement similar functionality for both your image models, then you should not repeat your self and create only one polymorphic model

Keep your code short: If your 2 photo models will implement different functionality it's better to separate them to keep your code clean and easy to read and maintain

And, you certainly know already, but you can create different style for your geometries, so if you choose the polymorphic way you'd just have to find different names :thumbnail_car, :thumbnail_car_model and so on

Answer (score 2):

Use STI(single table inheritance) made separate CarPhoto model inherited by Photo model and overriding photo's model methods. The CarPhoto model uses the same photos tables.

```
class CarPhoto < Photo
  # In this override the photo model methods and validations of you car's photo.
end
```

I think this will helps you.

Answer (score 1):

1. You could also go the route in which you specify the size of the photo in your **Photo** model, by specifying a *length* and a *width* which you would populate when you resize the image server-side before you save the image.
2. Save two versions of your image. The thumbnail and a larger size. You will end up with more files on S3, but space is cheap - and it's much less intensive with regards to rendering. By having the two sizes, you also rid yourself of dealing with resolution reductions for thumbnails that will look less than desirable.

For example, you could set up your model as such:

```
Photo
  name
  file_type
```

So for *monkey.png*, you'd have `Photo(name: "monkey", file_type: "png")`
Then you would resize your image to your desired large format and save it as "monkey_large.png" and your thumbnail, "monkey_thumb.png" (or, alternatively, save 'monkey.png' to two seperate directories `large/` and `thumb/`).

So at display time, you could have a method on Photo doing a simple string concatenation (using the different directory method for saving images):

```
def image_path_thumbnail
  "#{<s3 path>/thumb/#{image_name}.{image_file_type}"
end

def image_path_large
  "#{<s3 path>/large/#{image_name}.{image_file_type}"
end
```

Also, take a look at [PaperClip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) for file uploads. They have S3 integration and a multitude of tutorials exist online.